# Create a function out of main that merge two arrays C++

Tags: c++, arrays, merge

In my main function i have:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int merge(int a[], int b[]);

 int dim1, dim2;


cin >> dim1 >> dim2;
 int arrc[dim1];
 int arrd[dim2];
```

I fill my arrays with:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < dim1; i++){
        cin >> arrc[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < dim2; i++){
        cin >> arrd[i];
    }
```

Out of main func, then i have:

```
int merge(int a[], int b[]){
    int q;
    int arrf[q];
 //Code here
}
```

How can I make my int q be the sum of dim1 and dim2?
I tried to declare merge function as:

```
 int merge(int a[something], int b[something2]);
```

but I got errors...

Comment: What is merge (logically) supposed to return?

Comment: There are no VLA's in c++. Your code is fundametally wrong.

Comment: It should return an array whose number of elements is the sum of the number of elements of my two starter arrays

Comment: Welcome to C++ and its dynamic size array: [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: `//Code here` .... along with "I got errors..." not a very complete question...

Comment: _@150_ _"but I got errors..."_ Isn't a particularly precise problem description.

Answer (score 4):

The code

```
int arrc[dim1];
int arrd[dim2];
```

Is not valid C++.  C++ does not have variable length arrays, so for that to work, `dim1` and `dim2` would have to be compile-time constants.  Instead, you will have to use either dynamically-allocated arrays, or better yet, [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (which is basically just a wrapper for a dynamically-allocated array that can re-allocate to allow the array to grow):

```
std::vector<int> arrc(dim1);
std::vector<int> arrd(dim2);
```

Similarly, you would then change your `merge` function's signature to be something like:

```
std::vector<int> merge(const std::vector<int>& a, const std::vector<int>& b)
{
    std::vector<int> ret;
    for (int i : a)
    {
        ret.push_back(i);
    }
    for (int i : b)
    {
        ret.push_back(i);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

You don't actually need to implement your own `merge` function though.  The C++ standard library already provides [`std::merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge), which you would like this:

```
std::vector<int> arrc(dim1);
std::vector<int> arrd(dim2);
// Fill arrc and arrd somehow

std::vector<int> merged;
std::merge(arrc.begin(), arrc.end(),
           arrd.begin(), arrd.end(),
           std::back_inserter(merged));
```

Comment: Worth to mention there's already [`std::merge()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge).

Comment: @TheDude added a note about `std::merge`.  God, I can't wait until we get ranges to make those invocations less verbose.

Comment: _"... to make those invocations less verbose."_ Using `std::begin(arrc)` and `std::end(arrc)`, etc. helps a little bit IMO. At least with explicit `using` directives.

Comment: Since you know the size of the final vector, it probably makes sense to do `ret.reserve(a.size() + b.size());` before stuffing things into it. Also, you can ditch the first `for` loop by just creating `ret` from `a` like `std::vector<int> ret{a.begin(), a.end()};`.

Answer (score 0):

C-style arrays can't be directly returned from a function, and when they're passed to a function by value they implicitly convert to a pointer, losing their size information.

To preserve the size information of a C-style array, you can take it by reference in a template function like so:

```
#include <cstddef>

template<std::size_t N>
int &last_element(int(&a)[N])
{
    return a[N - 1];
}
```

While C-style arrays can't be directly returned from a function, [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) from the standard library can.

```
#include <array>

std::array<int, 3> get_array()
{
    return {};
}
```

Putting the two together, you can do something like

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>

namespace detail {

template<std::size_t N1, std::size_t N2>
inline auto join_(const int a1[], const int a2[]) noexcept
{
    std::array<int, N1 + N2> joined;

    std::copy_n(a1, N1, joined.begin());
    std::copy_n(a2, N2, joined.begin() + N1);

    return joined;
}

}//detail

// std::array overload
template<std::size_t N1, std::size_t N2>
auto join(const std::array<int, N1> &a1, const std::array<int, N2> &a2) noexcept
{
    return detail::join_<N1, N2>(a1.data(), a2.data());
}

// C-style array overload
template<std::size_t N1, std::size_t N2>
auto join(const int(&a1)[N1], const int(&a2)[N2]) noexcept
{
    return detail::join_<N1, N2>(a1, a2);
}
```